# Calling clip function in pyQGIS from python console?

Tags: pyqgis, clip

Is there a way to call the clip function in QQGIS from the python console? It is found under geoprocessing tools in the vector menu.

Comment: Ok I fixed it by using the multiparts to singleparts function first. Then it works.

Answer (score 11):

Sure
You can get the function from the processing toolbox. Here's how to use it: As per http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

From the console you can get a list of all the algorithms available which contain the word "clip" by typing:

```
import processing
processing.alglist("clip")
```

Then you could find out how to use what appears the most appropriate function with:

```
processing.alghelp("qgis:clip")
```

Then simply use the algorithm in your script as follows:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:clip",inputlayer,overlaylayer,"output_file.shp")
```

Note: The algorithm will work only on slected features"

Note above code is invalid for 3.0+
for the alglist example you can do:

```
print([a.id() for a in gsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms() if "clip" in a.id()])
```

for the alghelp example you can do:

```
processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:clip")
```

For QGIS3 see this question:

[What is the new alglist and alghelp in QGIS 3.0 Processing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276976/what-is-the-new-alglist-and-alghelp-in-qgis-3-0-processing)

Comment: Sorry for bringing this topic to life again, but never made this work, and now I need it again. In the pyhton console I get the two layers by `Layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()` and `InputLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()`. Then I use `processing.runandload("qgis:clip",InputLayer,Layer,"output_file.shp")` and the new layer is added to the Layers menu with the name _Clipped_. But the layer is empty. If I use these two layers with the clip function within Qgis, the output layer has the lines from the clipping. Anyone who what can be wrong? I do not get any errors.

Comment: It works if I use two polygons, but one of my layers are a line and not polygon. It contains several lines, and I can use this layer for clipping when doing it in Qgis.

Comment: You need to have the features that you want to clip selectged. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: How would one do this without actually creating shapefiles? I have a layer with hundreds of disc-shaped polygons that I want to iterate through, using each as an overlay for a single layer of point data. Can I just get a list of QgsFeature objects instead somehow?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question

Comment: Thank you MrPurple -- I didn't know if it was appropriate to create a whole new question, but I'll do so now.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have a layer called "overlay" and another one called "layer_to_clip" loaded.

```
# get the overlay layer in the console
overlay_layer = [x for x in iface.legendInterface().layers() if x.name() == 'overlay'][0]

# get the layer to clip in the console
layer_to_clip = [x for x in iface.legendInterface().layers() if x.name() == 'layer_to_clip'][0]

# run the algorithm and output the results in /tmp/output.shp

processing.runalg("qgis:clip", overlay_layer, layer_to_clip, "/tmp/output.shp")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest PyQGIS version it should work as follows

```py
from qgis.core import *

def clipping(layer_1, layer_2):
    layer_clip = processing.run('qgis:clip',
        {'INPUT': layer_1,
        'OVERLAY': layer_2,
        'OUTPUT': "memory:"}
    )["OUTPUT"]

    return QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_clip)

your_layer_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer_name_1')[0] # main layer
your_layer_2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer_name_2')[0] # secondary layer

clipping(your_layer_1, your_layer_2)
```

*Note:* The output of algorithm will have the same geometry as the main layer

---

**References:**

- [Docs » QGIS User Guide » Processing providers and algorithms » QGIS algorithm provider » Vector overlay](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip)