# Is there a call in pyqgis that clips a layer similarly to the Geoprocessing Tool?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I've loaded two shape files using pyqgis like so:

```
data_layer = QgsVectorLayer("lines.shp", "highways", "ogr")
clip_layer = QgsVectorLayer("polygon.shp", "highways", "ogr")
```

As the names of the source files suggest one of the files consists of line geometry data and the other of polygon data. I'd like to do the GUI operation Vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Clip operation in code. Something like: `new_layer = QgsClip(clip_layer, data_layer)`

I notice [QgsClipper](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsClipper.html) in the API docs but that only does rectangular clipping as far as I can see.

Is there a function that does what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the QGIS algorithms you can use de processing module ([Using processing algorithms from the console](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html))

```
import processing
processing.alglist("clip")
Clip------------------------------------------------->qgis:clip
Clip Multiple Rasters-------------------------------->script:clipmultiplerasters
Clip grid with polygon------------------------------->saga:clipgridwithpolygon
Clip points with polygons---------------------------->saga:clippointswithpolygons
Clip raster by extent-------------------------------->gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent
Clip raster by mask layer---------------------------->gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer
Clip vectors by extent------------------------------->gdalogr:clipvectorsbyextent
Clip vectors by polygon------------------------------>gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon
```

The one you were looking for is `qgis:clip`

```
processing.alghelp("qgis:clip")
ALGORITHM: Clip
   INPUT <ParameterVector>
   OVERLAY <ParameterVector>
   OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

This command is illustrated in many answers in GIS SE -> [Is there a way to call the clip function in pyQGIS from the python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56832/is-there-a-way-to-call-the-clip-function-in-pyqgis-from-the-python-console)

Comment: This is the correct answer and works fine when I do this within the QGIS console. I should have added that I want to do this in a standalone script. When I do so it fails with Unable to execute algorithm

Comment: This is the correct answer and works fine when I do this within the QGIS console. I should have added that I want to do this in a standalone script. When I do so it fails with "Unable to execute algorithm. Wrong parameter value: path/to/lines.shp". Is there an obvious answer here or should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Next code:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

feats1 = [ feature for feature in layers[0].getFeatures() ]

feats2 = [ feature for feature in layers[1].getFeatures() ]

n_feats1 = len(feats1)
n_feats2 = len(feats2)

#comprehension list
geom3 = [ feats1[i].geometry().intersection(feats2[j].geometry()).exportToWkt()
          for i in range(n_feats1)
          for j in range(n_feats2)
          if feats1[i].geometry().intersects(feats2[j].geometry()) ]

for item in geom3:
    print item
```

it was ran at the Python Console for the two vector layers (**line** and **polygon6** equivalents to your **data_layer** and **clip_layer**; respectively) of following image:

[image]

and I got this:

[image]

Geometry **geom3** (lines that intersect the polygon) is in WKT notation and it was visualized with the **QuickWKT** plugin.