# What is the new alglist and alghelp in QGIS 3.0 Processing?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

Accessing the new QGIS 3.0 processing scripts through the Python console is proving to be a challenge for me, especially since the old processing.alglist() and processing.alghelp() commands appear to be defunct.

- How does one call up a list of processing scripts?
- How does one call up the help info for an individual script?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- How does one call up a list of processing scripts?

  ```
   QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms()
  ```

  If you want to print a readable list of algorithm ids and names, you can do this:

  ```
   for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
       print(f"{alg.id()} --> {alg.displayName()}")
  ```
- How does one call up the help info for an individual script?

  ```
   processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:refactorfields")
  ```

See https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_Processing for details and recommendations from QGIS developers.