# Using QGIS Processing algorithms from PyQGIS standalone scripts (outside of GUI)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, standalone

I am writing a script which must work outside of QGIS GUI. I call some API functions from qgis.core but I would like to use the processing plugin.

I am able to import processing with `sys.path.append()` but I cannot run any process. Moreover, all "native" algs are missing in `QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms()`

Is it possible to run processing that way?

```py
import os, sys
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer('data/ROUTE_PRIMAIRE.SHP')
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer('data/ROUTE_SECONDAIRE.SHP')

processing.run('qgis:union', layer1, layer2, 'test.shp') # returns nothing
```

I am using QGIS 3.0.1 on Debian 9.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can run a QGIS Processing algorithm in standalone (no GUI) mode in this way:

```
import sys
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication, 
     QgsProcessingFeedback, 
     QgsVectorLayer
)

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('/docs/dev/qgis/build/output/python/plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/geodata/lines_1.shp', 'layer 1', 'ogr')
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/geodata/lines_2.shp', 'layer 2', 'ogr')

# You can see what parameters are needed by the algorithm  
# using: processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:union")
params = { 
    'INPUT' : layer1,
    'OVERLAY' : layer2, 
    'OUTPUT' : '/path/to/output_layer.gpkg|layername=output'
}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276979/4972 for a list of algorithms
res = processing.run('qgis:union', params, feedback=feedback)
res['OUTPUT'] # Access your output layer
```

### Note for QGIS versions LESS THAN 3.16.5

If you want to use a native algorithm (i.e., an algorithm from the native provider, whose algorithms are written in C++), you need to add the provider after initializing Processing:

```
import sys
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication, 
     QgsProcessingFeedback, 
     QgsVectorLayer
)
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('/docs/dev/qgis/build/output/python/plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

layer = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/geodata/lines.shp', 'my layer', 'ogr')

# You can see what parameters are needed by the algorithm  
# using: processing.algorithmHelp("native:extractvertices")
params = {
    'INPUT': layer,
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276979/4972 for a list of algorithms
res = processing.run("native:extractvertices", params, feedback=feedback)
res['OUTPUT'] # Access your output layer
```

---

*Note: If you actually wrote **your own Processing algorithm** and would like to run it in a standalone PyQGIS script, see: [Using custom Processing algorithm from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408684/loading-custom-qgsprocessingalgorithm-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui)*

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Somehow a very similar code dosen't work. See more: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286281/why-qgis-3-0-3-nativeextractvertices-algorithm-dosent-work-properly-it-stand

Comment: I try running a QGIS algorithm in a QGIS Plugin, does this work the same way? Because I can't make it run

Comment: yes the code work should work with gui but you need a lot of other things to make it run! you should take a look at the Plugin Builder extension

Comment: I was able to just copy `import processing` then the `processing.run(.  . . )` snippet into my plugin's `if result:` clause and it ran great :) Thank you!

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Great stuff, still when I run the script I get na error `qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms` , I've read stackoverflow on this but no anwser seems to work, I'm using PyCharm 2020.1 / QGIS 3.12, appreciate help!

Comment: I don't know why this has been accepted as the correct answer (maybe it's just outdated) but for those interested in using the qgis processing module, here's how you import it `from qgis import processing`. As for `from processing.core.Processing import Processing; Processing.initialize()` it's no longer required.

Answer (score 3):

I had an error:

> NameError: name 'QgsNativeAlgorithms' is not defined

when I tried to use a native algorithm as above, in an OSGeo4W install that included QGIS 3.4.4.

The solution turned out to be a missing import:

```py
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
```

(from [QGIS 3.4/3.6 standalone script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315840/qgis-3-4-3-6-standalone-script))

Answer (score 2):

For standalone QGIS processing, you can now use `qgis_process` command line (available since QGIS 3.14, doc at https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/standalone). Because of this, it's now possible to the following

```
qgis_process run native:union --INPUT=/path/to/geodata/lines_1.shp --OVERLAY=/path/to/geodata/lines_2.shp --OUTPUT="/tmp/output_layer.gpkg
```

You will suffer from one limitation at the moment compared to Python standalone approach: you can't specify the layer name output e.g https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38272