# How to adjust Python code from PyQGIS 2 to 3 to create a buffer on a shapefile

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, pyqgis, qgis-3

I am starting to learn PyQGIS and following tutorials online. However, I have QGIS 3.0 and most of the tutorials use QGIS version 2. I am trying to do a buffer on a point shapefile, but only have the code for Qgis 2. I have looked at the backwards incompatible changes (https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) but cannot work out how to adjust the code. The 'GeometryAnalyzer' class, which contained the buffer function in Qgis 2 no longer exists, so I am not sure where to find it now. I am sure there is a simple solution..

The code for Qgis 2 as far as I know is as follows:

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsGeometryAnalzer
layer = iface.activeLayer()
QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, 'OutputFilePath/FileName.shp', 0.5, False, False, -1)
```

How can this be adjusted to Qgis 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The API changes page](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) says:

> QgsGeometryAnalyzer. Use the equivalent Processing algorithms instead.

`processing.algorithmHelp("native:buffer")` gives

```
processing.run('native:buffer', {"INPUT": lineLayer, "DISTANCE": 5, "OUTPUT": resultLayer})
```

Comment: Also worth checking out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis3-processing-algorithms-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui/279937#279937