# Running qgis processing algorithm in qgis plugin

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I try to run a qgis native algorithm in a qgis plugin and I can't make it work. I follow espescially [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis3-processing-algorithms-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui/279937#279937) answer on a GIS SE question. I will add my whole code at the end of the question, since I do not know where the fault is located at and I'm new to pyqgis.

If I start my plugin I can add a vectorlayer from the layerslist and choose the output destination. Those are supposed to be the input and output of the algorithm. But when I run it I just get an errormessage from QGIS, but the errorlog contains no python errors, even though it says so. So I am stuck at that point. On top of it, after closing QGIS, the desktop shortcut didn't work anymore, because the .exe was not found (it was supposed to be located at C:\OSGeo4W64\bin, but it is not anymore. It seems to be deleted somehow).

Heres the code. At first I import everything, what I think is needed and with the function "IntersectionsToNodes" I try running the algorithm. I use QGIS 3.2.

```
import os.path
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

#Access the processing algorithm
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([],False)
qgs.initQgis()

#Folder location of processing plugin
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
# Import the code for the dialog
from .befahrungsplanung_dialog import BefahrungsplanungDialog


class Befahrungsplanung:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

def __init__(self, iface):
    """Constructor.

    :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
        which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
        application at run time.
    :type iface: QgsInterface
    """
    # Save reference to the QGIS interface
    self.iface = iface
    # initialize plugin directory
    self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    # initialize locale
    locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
    locale_path = os.path.join(
        self.plugin_dir,
        'i18n',
        'Befahrungsplanung_{}.qm'.format(locale))

    if os.path.exists(locale_path):
        self.translator = QTranslator()
        self.translator.load(locale_path)

        if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

    # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
    self.dlg = BefahrungsplanungDialog()

    # Declare instance attributes
    self.actions = []
    self.menu = self.tr(u'&Befahrungsplanung')
    # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
    self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'Befahrungsplanung')
    self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'Befahrungsplanung')

    self.dlg.directory.clear()
    self.dlg.push_directory.clicked.connect(self.output)
    self.dlg.button_box.clicked.connect(self.IntersectionsToNodes)

# noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
def tr(self, message):
    """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

    We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

    :param message: String for translation.
    :type message: str, QString

    :returns: Translated version of message.
    :rtype: QString
    """
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
    return QCoreApplication.translate('Befahrungsplanung', message)

def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
    """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

    :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
        path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
    :type icon_path: str

    :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
    :type text: str

    :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
    :type callback: function

    :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
        by default. Defaults to True.
    :type enabled_flag: bool

    :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
        be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
    :type add_to_menu: bool

    :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
        be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
    :type add_to_toolbar: bool

    :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
        hovers over the action.
    :type status_tip: str

    :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
    :type parent: QWidget

    :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
        mouse pointer hovers over the action.

    :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
        added to self.actions list.
    :rtype: QAction
    """

    icon = QIcon(icon_path)
    action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
    action.triggered.connect(callback)
    action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

    if status_tip is not None:
        action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

    if whats_this is not None:
        action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

    if add_to_toolbar:
        self.toolbar.addAction(action)

    if add_to_menu:
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
            self.menu,
            action)

    self.actions.append(action)

    return action

def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/befahrungsplanung/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Befahrungsplanung'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.layerlist()

def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&Befahrungsplanung'),
            action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
    # remove the toolbar
    del self.toolbar

def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass

def layerlist(self):
    """Load all linevector layers"""
    self.dlg.layerlist.clear()
    layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    vector_layers = []
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
            vector_layers.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.layerlist.addItems(vector_layers)

def output(self):
    """Choose Shapefile or Geopackage as Output File"""
    filename = str(QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg,
                                                "Output Datei auswählen ",
                                                "",
                                                "shapefile (*.shp);;geopackage (*.gpkg)")[0])
    self.dlg.directory.setText(filename)

def IntersectionsToNodes(self):
    """Transforms all intersections in the selected layer into nodes"""

    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    inputIndex = self.dlg.layerlist.currentIndex()
    input = layers[inputIndex]

    filename = self.dlg.directory.text()
    output = open(filename, 'w')

    params = {
        'INPUT' : input,
        'LINES' : input,
        'OUTPUT' : output
    }

    res = processing.run('native:splitwithlines', params)
    res['OUTPUT']
    #processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:splitwithlines")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question. I made it way too complicated in the beginning.

If you are working in the QGIS interface (as I do with a plugin for QGIS), all you have to do is to `import processing` to make the QGIS native algorithms work. I added the whole reworked and working code for comparrison issues.

```
import os.path
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog
from qgis.core import *
import processing

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
# Import the code for the dialog
from .befahrungsplanung_dialog import BefahrungsplanungDialog


class Befahrungsplanung:
"""QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

def __init__(self, iface):
    """Constructor.

    :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
        which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
        application at run time.
    :type iface: QgsInterface
    """
    # Save reference to the QGIS interface
    self.iface = iface
    # initialize plugin directory
    self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    # initialize locale
    locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
    locale_path = os.path.join(
        self.plugin_dir,
        'i18n',
        'Befahrungsplanung_{}.qm'.format(locale))

    if os.path.exists(locale_path):
        self.translator = QTranslator()
        self.translator.load(locale_path)

        if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

    # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
    self.dlg = BefahrungsplanungDialog()

    # Declare instance attributes
    self.actions = []
    self.menu = self.tr(u'&Befahrungsplanung')
    # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
    self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'Befahrungsplanung')
    self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'Befahrungsplanung')

    self.dlg.directory.clear()
    self.dlg.push_directory.clicked.connect(self.output)
    self.dlg.button_box.clicked.connect(self.IntersectionsToNodes)

# noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
def tr(self, message):
    """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

    We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

    :param message: String for translation.
    :type message: str, QString

    :returns: Translated version of message.
    :rtype: QString
    """
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
    return QCoreApplication.translate('Befahrungsplanung', message)

def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
    """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

    :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
        path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
    :type icon_path: str

    :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
    :type text: str

    :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
    :type callback: function

    :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
        by default. Defaults to True.
    :type enabled_flag: bool

    :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
        be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
    :type add_to_menu: bool

    :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
        be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
    :type add_to_toolbar: bool

    :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
        hovers over the action.
    :type status_tip: str

    :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
    :type parent: QWidget

    :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
        mouse pointer hovers over the action.

    :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
        added to self.actions list.
    :rtype: QAction
    """

    icon = QIcon(icon_path)
    action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
    action.triggered.connect(callback)
    action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

    if status_tip is not None:
        action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

    if whats_this is not None:
        action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

    if add_to_toolbar:
        self.toolbar.addAction(action)

    if add_to_menu:
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
            self.menu,
            action)

    self.actions.append(action)

    return action

def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/befahrungsplanung/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Befahrungsplanung'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.layerlist()

def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&Befahrungsplanung'),
            action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
    # remove the toolbar
    del self.toolbar

def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass

def layerlist(self):
    """Load all linevector layers"""
    self.dlg.layerlist.clear()
    layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    vector_layers = []
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
            vector_layers.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.layerlist.addItems(vector_layers)

def output(self):
    """Choose Shapefile or Geopackage as Output File"""
    filename = str(QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg,
                                                "Output Datei auswählen ",
                                                "",
                                                "shapefile (*.shp);;geopackage (*.gpkg)")[0])
    self.dlg.directory.setText(filename)

def IntersectionsToNodes(self):
    """Transforms all intersections of the selected layer in the function layerslist into nodes"""

    layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    inputIndex = self.dlg.layerlist.currentIndex()
    input = layers[inputIndex]

    output = self.dlg.directory.text()

    params = {
        'INPUT' : input,
        'LINES' : input,
        'OUTPUT' : output
    }

    res = processing.run('native:splitwithlines', params)
```