# QGIS 3 access "extract by location" processing tool with python

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am trying to use the "Extract by location" algorithm in a standalone script with QGIS 3.4.7 and Python 3.7.
The algorithm, however is not listed in available algorithms as listed with: `processingRegistry().algorithms()`.
Since there have been a lot of changes in QGIS 3, and the docs are not complete, I can't figure out how to use it.
The algorithm exists in the app, since I can access it and use it from the QGIS app itself.
Of the algorithms that have anything with 'location' or 'select', I can only use:

- `qgis:joinbylocationsummary`
- `qgis:joinattributesbylocation`
- `qgis:randomselectionwithinsubsets`
- `qgis:selectbyattribute`
- `qgis:selectbyexpression`
- `qgis:extractspecifiedvertices`

So I guess the processing tool for "Extract by location" is not using a dedicated algorithm object anymore, and it is using some other tool. Can anyone suggest, how to check what method/class/object is used to run "Extract by location" in QGIS 3?

In QGIS 2.x the algorithm was used with 
`processing.runalg(...)` but this is not used anymore, so all guides for running algorithms with python now do not apply.

My code starts with

```
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.setPrefixPath(r"D:\QG\qgis-ltr", True)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.append(r'D:\QG\qgis-ltr\python\plugins')
from processing.core import Processing
Processing.Processing.initialize()
```

I use this code to list the algorithms:

```
qgs.processingRegistry().algorithms()
```

And this code to run one:

```
Processing.Processing.runAlgorithm('qgs:extractbylocation', <args>)
```

Which throws:

```
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm qgs:extractbylocation not found
```

as if the algorithm was not available.

The QGIS app allows to use it with no problem.
. 
[image]

Comment: See [Using QGIS3 Processing algorithms from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis3-processing-algorithms-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui/279937#279937) and add the native algorithms to your Processing. Then you can access that algorithm as `natve:extractbylocation`.

Comment: @German Carrillo thank you, and I've seen that topic before, but I didn't understand the distinction between native and non-native algorithms. Please produce an naswer so I can mark one.

Comment: Native algorithms are written in C++. In your standalone Python script you need to add them manually after importing Processing. Otherwise, you won't get access to any native (C++) algorithm. The post I mentioned in the previous comment says even more, giving you an example. After adding the Native provider, you can run the extract by location algorithm like this: `processing.run('native:extractbylocation', params)`. See what parameters are required using `processing.algorithmHelp("native:extractbylocation")`.