# Multiplying rasters in standalone PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to multiply some rasters in a standalone python environment. I have done it successfully in the QGIS python environment, and manually in QGIS, but when I run the following code, nothing occurs, nor do I receive any indication of an error.

```
alg_params_cdsm_filt1 = {
'INPUT_A':home_folder+'\\CDSM.tif',
'BAND_A':1,
'INPUT_B':home_folder+'\\buildings_buffered_raster.tif',
'BAND_B':None,
'INPUT_C':None,'BAND_C':None,'INPUT_D':None,'BAND_D':None,'INPUT_E':None,'BAND_E':None,'INPUT_F':None,'BAND_F':None,
'FORMULA':'A*B',
'NO_DATA':None,
'RTYPE':5,
'OPTIONS':'',
'EXTRA':'',
'OUTPUT':home_folder+'\\CDSM_filt1.tif'}

 cdsm_filt1 = processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator", alg_params_cdsm_filt1)
```

I took the code from the QGIS processing history when it had run successfully.

Why does nothing happen?

Comment: Wondering if you put all the require code to run QGIS processing in standalone mode e.g https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279937/638

Comment: What does `print(cdsm_filt1)` return?

Comment: print(cdsm_filt1)
{'OUTPUT': 'C:\\Users\\weedingb\\Desktop\\utas_solweig_run\\CDSM_filt1.tif'}
Seems bizarre!

Comment: So it seems, it works as you do not get error messages. Does `CDSM_filt1.tif` contain the "right"/expected content?

Comment: No file named CDSM_filt1.tif appears in the directory!

Comment: Really do not know how to help more... Sorry!