# QgsProcessingException when running standalone script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

My task is to run QGIS in standalone script. All the modules import correctly and I am running QGIS in conda environment. Error occurs when running the `processing.run()` command

```
QgsProcessingException: Process gdal2xyz.bat failed to start. Either gdal2xyz.bat is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to run the program.
```

Here is the code I am running. Only the last line causes error.

```py
import sys
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication
)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

processing.run("gdal:gdal2xyz", {'INPUT':r'D:\dummy\K.tif','BAND':1,'CSV':True,
                                'OUTPUT':r'D:\dummy\K.csv'})
```

Since I am using conda environment, `QGIS_PREFIX_PATH`, `PYTHONPATH` are already set as shown below:

[image]

I am unable to comprehend the error and resolve it. I followed the instructions from [Using QGIS 3 Processing algorithms from PyQGIS standalone scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874). Running Python 3.9.4 and QGIS 3.18.3.