# User friendly list of processing algorithms in the QGIS 3 python console

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3, qgis-python-console

The QGIS user guide section [Using processing algorithms from the console](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html) has not yet been updated for QGIS 3 and while a [previously answered question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276976/what-is-the-new-alglist-and-alghelp-in-qgis-3-0-processing) will do the trick with some extra work, it is not as easy and user friendly as the old `alglist()`

In the user guide the following commands are presented, resulting in a user-friendly list:

```
import processing
processing.alglist()
```

This still works in the QGIS 2.18.18 python console. Using an algorithm's id one can then use e.g.

```
processing.alghelp("qgis:dissolve")
```

to learn about the algorithm's required parameters etc.

Are there any equivalent functions in QGIS 3?

Using something like `print([str(e.provider().name()) + ":" + str(e.name()) for e in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms()])` gets me closer, but still not equivalent in readability to `alglist()`.

Comment: I've found in [the GitHub history of the processing plugin](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commits/master/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py) that `alglist()` and `alghelp()` were renamed to `printAlgorithms()` and `algorithmHelp()`. Since then they seem to have been moved to `qgis.core.QgsProcessingRegistry` but I can't find any replacement for `alglist()` there.

Comment: Using the `QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms()` function as suggested in [the previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276976/what-is-the-new-alglist-and-alghelp-in-qgis-3-0-processing) returns a list of QgsProcessingAlgorithm objects and so does not on its own provide the quick and user friendly method previously found in `alglist()`.

Comment: Just added more details to the answer showing how to emulate the output of `alglist()` in QGIS 2.x.

Comment: Thanks @GermánCarrillo, your example to get a readable list from the console was very neat. Why not reintroduce `QgsApplication.processingRegistry().printAlgorithms()` using that example?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, something to suggest to QGIS devs for sure!