# Use QGIS `processing.run(...., alg_params)` from OSGEO4W shell in QGIS Dev 3.26

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, qgis.core

I've created a simple tool using the code from save model to automate processing. It runs as expected in the QGIS python console but does not work from osgeo4w shell.

I have tried the process in https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-qgis-spatial-algorithms-with-python-scripts-4bf980e39898 and https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/running_qgis_jobs.html

I have also tried Spyder in Conda but I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'`

Even looking at similar questions here, I see it's been an issue for different versions and so they don't work either.

**--- UPDATE**

It ended up being some install error and uninstalling and re-installing QGIS worked. To run the python to allow for `import qgis` to work you have to open the bat file - C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python-qgis.bat and then you can import qgis however `processing.run` is not part of it so I still need to know how to run algs as below.

---

I need to run algs like

```
from qgis.core import *
# Points to path
    alg_params = {
                'CLOSE_PATH': False,
                'GROUP_EXPRESSION': '',
                'INPUT': outputs['CreatePointsLayerFromTable']['OUTPUT'],
                'NATURAL_SORT': False,
                'ORDER_EXPRESSION': '',
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
    outputs['PointsToPath'] = processing.run('native:pointstopath', alg_params)
    print ('3_PointsToPath')
```

Is there a guide like the examples above?

I want to automate the running of this py file to process data weekly. So alternatively is there a way to launch qgis with this py file to process and close?

The whole code that I want to run in qgis_processing is below.

```
import os, glob, re
from qgis.core import *
in_dir=r'Z:/Mowing_Automated_Reporting/Input'
out_dir=r'Z:/Mowing_Automated_Reporting/Working/Draft_Output'
os.chdir(in_dir)

def Clean_Mower_Data(in_file,out_file, max_speed, max_length):
    # Extract by expression
    outputs = {}
    max_speed_alg='\'"Speed KmH"  < '+ str(max_speed)+'\'' 
    print (max_speed_alg)
    alg_params = {
                'EXPRESSION': '"Speed KmH"  < '+ str(max_speed) ,
                'INPUT': in_file,
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT #'Z:/My Drive/Mangoesmapping/Spatial Projects/2022/DSC/015_DSC_Mowing_Automated_Reporting/working/1.tab',
                }
                
    outputs['ExtractByExpression']=processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params)
    print ('1_ExtractByExpression')

    # Create points layer from table
    alg_params = {
                'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByExpression']['OUTPUT'],
                'MFIELD': '',
                'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
                'XFIELD': 'Longitude',
                'YFIELD': 'Latitude',
                'ZFIELD': '',
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
    outputs['CreatePointsLayerFromTable'] = processing.run('native:createpointslayerfromtable', alg_params)
    print ('2_CreatePointsLayerFromTable')

    # Points to path
    alg_params = {
                'CLOSE_PATH': False,
                'GROUP_EXPRESSION': '',
                'INPUT': outputs['CreatePointsLayerFromTable']['OUTPUT'],
                'NATURAL_SORT': False,
                'ORDER_EXPRESSION': '',
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
    outputs['PointsToPath'] = processing.run('native:pointstopath', alg_params)
    print ('3_PointsToPath')

    # Explode lines
    alg_params = {
                'INPUT': outputs['PointsToPath']['OUTPUT'],
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
    outputs['ExplodeLines'] = processing.run('native:explodelines', alg_params)
    print ('4_ExplodeLines')

    # Extract by expression
    alg_params = {
                'EXPRESSION': '$length <'+str(max_length),               
                'INPUT': outputs['ExplodeLines']['OUTPUT'],
                'OUTPUT': out_file
            }
    processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params)
    print ('5_Extracted')
    
#    # Fix geometries
#    alg_params = {
#            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByExpression2']['OUTPUT'],
#            'OUTPUT': out_file
#        }
#    processing.run('native:fixgeometries', alg_params)
#    print ('6_Fixed')
    

filelist=glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in filelist:
    
    #Process with speed/length limits
    fn=os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    max_speed=30
    max_length =150
    fn=s=re.findall("^DeviceDataExport_(.*)_\d*-\d*-\d*.*",fn)
    fn=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+_', '', fn[0])+'__s'+str(max_speed)+'_l'+str(max_length)
    in_file=os.path.join(in_dir,file)
    out_file=out_dir+"//"+fn+".tab"
    Clean_Mower_Data(in_file,out_file, max_speed, max_length)
    print ('processed: %s --to--> %s' % (file, fn))
    
    #Process without speed/length limits
    fn=os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    max_speed=999
    max_length =99999
    fn=re.findall("^DeviceDataExport\s(.*)\s\d*-\d*-\d*.*",fn)
    fn=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', fn[0])
    in_file=os.path.join(in_dir,file)
    out_file=out_dir+"//"+fn+".tab"
    Clean_Mower_Data(in_file,out_file, max_speed, max_length)
    print ('processed: %s --to--> %s' % (file, fn))
```

Comment: Have you tried to make a processing algorithm with your code and call it outside with `qgis_process` ? https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/standalone.html?#using-processing-from-the-command-line

Comment: Does OSGeo4W come with a python-qgis.bat file? If so, can you launching the script through that? It should set up the environment correctly.

Comment: @J.Monticolo yes I have tried this but am confused on how to launch a py file using this. I have added the whole py file content to the question.

Comment: @bugmenot123 -  If I run the `python-qgis-dev.bat` file I get the following errors `>>> import qgis  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 78, in <module> from qgis.PyQt import QtCore                                                                                          File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in <module>                                          from PyQt5.QtCore import *   ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified module could not be found. `

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your OSGeo4W then, not your fault probably :) I'd suggest trying a clean and fresh install.

Comment: On reinstall of qgis (not just qgis dev) it allows `import qgis` but doesn't allow `processing.run` as it says `'processing' is not defined`

Comment: Hm, something is wrong with the PATHs. There are some Python-based workarounds if you Google for '"import processing" qgis site:gis.stackexchange.com' but adjusting your environment to include the path to the `qgis/python/plugins/` directory would be the cleanest way.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I have tried but it doesn't work. Does it work for you? if so can you share the contents of your bat file?

Comment: Sorry, I am on Linux. Glad you found some solution though it looks very hard. I wish things were easier on Windows :)

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work I had to do the following.

0 - Make sure there is nothing wrong with your install by first running `C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python-qgis.bat` and then try `import qgis`. If this gives errors the following will not work.

1 - Create a bat file with the code from C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python-qgis.bat and add the name of the python file at the end.

2 - Add the code from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279937/2891 to the python file. Note the settings for the `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath` and `sys.path.append`.

There a few things with using memory and a proper structure for commands to work. Will post details once I work it all out.

3 - Add a scheduled task as per https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/running_qgis_jobs.html

So my code for a windows system is

BAT file

```
@echo off
call "C:\OSGeo4W\bin\o4w_env.bat"
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%
python3 test_qgis.py
pause
```

Python file

```
import sys
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication, 
     QgsProcessingFeedback, 
     QgsVectorLayer
)

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

layer1 = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/geodata/lines_1.shp', 'layer 1', 'ogr')
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/geodata/lines_2.shp', 'layer 2', 'ogr')

# You can see what parameters are needed by the algorithm  
# using: processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:union")
params = { 
    'INPUT' : layer1,
    'OVERLAY' : layer2, 
    'OUTPUT' : '/path/to/output_layer.gpkg|layername=output'
}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276979/4972 for a list of algorithms
res = processing.run('qgis:union', params, feedback=feedback)
res['OUTPUT'] # Access your output layer
```